# JS object property undefined when called within object the first time

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects

Consider the following JS object, it has:

- x: a variable given value 100
- p: prints value of x, called immediately after creation
- y: prints value of x, called after object creation

When the value of Pipe.x is printed immediately during Object creation, for some reason Pipe.x is `undefined` but when P.y() is called, after an object, the Object has been created, the Value of Pipe.x is 100, as it should have been in the first place.

```
var Pipe = {
    x: 100,

    p: function(){
        console.log('p says x is ' + this.x); // prints y says x is undefined
    }(),    // call immediately

    y: function(){
        console.log('y says x is ' + this.x);
    }
}

Pipe.y();    // prints y says x is 100
```

Is there any JS object property I'm missing which makes Pipe.p() print undefined and P.y() print 100?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `this` Context depends on how it is being called.
When you call Pipe.y(), it is equivalent to obj.method() and `this` will be pointed to obj, in this case Pipe.

When p is being executed as IIFE, this is set to window and there is no x on window

Comment: Oh, that does make sense. Also, considering the above condition, is there any way that I can get value of x within p, even when p() is executed as IIFE?